# How to install Java SE Express version on Mac?

Tags: java

I'm looking for the "Java SE Express" jdk for developing an adobe AIR plugin. According to the book, "Java: in Parts" by John Malcun the link is there in the oracle website, but the link in the book doesn't work, and I can't find from searching.

Comment: What is this thingy written on Oracle website __" Mac OS X x64 183.35 MB     jdk-7u40-macosx-x64.dmg"__ on this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html). Leaving the question open, just since I got no `Mac OS X` to test my claim :(

Answer (score 3):

I hope you really searched well before blaming Oracle. here you go:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html

**EDIT**: There are freely available IDEs such as eclipse. You can download eclipse for MAC from :

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=macosx

Comment: Hey wise-guys. That is only the JDK. That it NOT an ide coding environment for java. Try again.

Comment: Sorry for the help, but if you have asked for, you would have got an answer! Java is not an IDE, there are many possible ones free and commercial

Comment: @Jim You didnt mention clearly in your question that you need an IDE. Anyways, check the edit for IDE download.

Comment: Of course Oracle supplies an IDE: NetBeans (you can even download NetBeans and the JDK as a bundle)